# SSAS Sort Action for Custom Measure

Tags: action, ssas

How do I create a sort action for a custom measure in my SSAS Cube? Is this possible? Maybe using some kind of drill through? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "a sort action for a measure"? Do you mean an Analysis Services action if a user clicks on a cell containing data using this measure? Do you mean you want to write a query where some set is sorted by the values its members have for this measure?

Comment: Yes that is what I was hoping for....

Comment: Which of the two alternatives is it that you were hoping for?